# Is there a way to output the tail on the fly?

Tags: linux, unix, tail

I was wondering if there was a way to run something like this ?

```
tail program -flag1 -flag2 agrument
```

I know this isn't correct but I essentially want to do what this would intuitively do if it worked.
The idea is to display the "tail" of the output of the program on the fly, without going through a the file system.

Comment: How can you ask about shell scripting and not know about pipes?

Comment: Switched to Linux from what? Windows has pipelines, so does OS X.

Comment: OK, I deserved that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 program -flag1 -flag2 argument | tail
```

Comment: Why `./program`? He never said the program was in his directory.

Comment: @barmar - force of habit

Answer (score 2):

Use a pipe:

```
program -flag1 -flag2 argument | tail
```

Any time you want to feed the output of one program to the input of another program, you use a pipeline:

```
program1 | program2
```